# How to make a static initialization block execute?

Tags: java

Searching for an explanation for why my static initialization block wouldn't execute, I found that a static initializer in a class never executes [if it references a final](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16853836/1864054).

So I tried to work around this by removing the 'final' from  MYWS_PROPS:

```
public class HibernateUtil {
  public static String MYWS_PROPS = "/myws.properties";

    private static final Logger LOG = Logger.getLogger(HibernateUtil.class.getName());
    private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();
    private static Properties sProps;

    static {
        try {
            sProps = new Properties();
            sProps.load(ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(MYWS_PROPS));
            LOG.info("Loaded (from " + MYWS_PROPS + ") connection url: " + sProps.getProperty("dburl"));
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.severe("Cannot find properties file " + MYWS_PROPS);
        }               
    }   



    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config = config.configure("resources/hibernate.cfg.xml");
            config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", sProps.getProperty("dburl"));    // <== NullPointerException!        
            SessionFactory session = config.buildSessionFactory();
            return session;
        }
        catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

}
```

**But that static block still wouldn't execute!**

What is the proper way to guarantee execution of a static block?

---

Update: All answers below mentioned the requirement to reference the class so that the static initialization will run. So I looked again at my stack trace and verified that the class is indeed referenced (otherwise, why would it throw an exception in that very same class method?)

```
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:76)
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil.<clinit>(HibernateUtil.java:38)
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.ServicePortImpl.<init>(ServicePortImpl.java:82)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:126)
        ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil.buildSessionFactory(HibernateUtil.java:67)
        ... 77 more
```

But to be on the safe side, I tried the **Class.forName** suggestion:

```
Class.forName("com.corp.dept.proj.myws.HibernateUtil");
mProps.load(ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(HibernateUtil.MYWS_PROPS));
```

**And that static block still wouldn't execute.**

So I tried to explicitly instantiate it:

```
HibernateUtil justExecTheDarnStaticBlock = new HibernateUtil();
mProps.load(ServiceUtils.class.getResourceAsStream(HibernateUtil.MYWS_PROPS));
```

**But that static block still wouldn't execute!**

What am I missing here?

Comment: `I found that a static initializer in a class never executes if it references a final.` This is not true. When do you expect the `static` block to execute?

Comment: Static initialization block is being ran when JVM (class loader - to be specific) loads StaticClass (when it is first time referenced in code). My understanding of the requirement for no final comes from here:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/16853836/1864054  What am I missing?

Comment: That has to do with `static final` fields which are also constant variables, not with initializer blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create an instance of the class the static block will certainly execute.

**EDIT:** The actual solution which was found in the comments is the following:

The `buildSessionFactory()` method is used in the initialization of `sessionFactory`. This depends on the static block having been called already but this isn't the case. If you call `sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();` in the static block rather than in its declaration and after `sProps` has been initialized the problem will disappear.

Comment: I did just that (see update in my OP) and the static block still wouldn't execute. Any idea why?

Comment: @Withheld You seem to be using the `buildSessionFactory()` method in the initialization of the `sessionFactory` constant. This depends on the static block having been called already; it may be that the order in which this runs is broken. Try calling `sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();` in the static block rather than in the declaration (and of course after `sProps` has been initialized).

Answer (score 3):

When dealing with static initalisation, **order matters**.

Take the following example:

```
public class StaticTest {
    private static final String someString = initSomeString();
    private static final String someOtherString = initSomeOtherString();
    private static final String whoops;

    static {
        System.out.println("static initializer");
        whoops = "whoops";
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someOtherString);
    }

    private static String initSomeString() {
        System.out.println("initSomeString");
        return "Initialised";
    }

    private static String initSomeOtherString() {
        System.out.println("initSomeOtherString");
        return whoops + "y daisy";
    }
}
```

The result of running this class is the following:

```
initSomeString
initSomeOtherString
static initialiser
nully daisy
```

Static initialisations occur *in the order in which they are declared*, meaning that `initSomeOtherString()` is called **before** the static initialiser block that initialises `whoops`. As a result, `whoops` is still `null` at that point, so the resulting `String` is `nully daisy` and not `whoopsy daisy`.

If I rearrange the class so that I initialise `someOtherString` *after* the static initialiser, I get what I wanted:

```
public class StaticTest {
    private static final String someString = initSomeString();
    private static final String whoops;

    static {
        System.out.println("static initialiser");
        whoops = "whoops";
    }

    private static final String someOtherString = initSomeOtherString();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(someOtherString);
    }

    private static String initSomeString() {
        System.out.println("initSomeString");
        return "Initialised";
    }

    private static String initSomeOtherString() {
        System.out.println("initSomeOtherString");
        return whoops + "y daisy";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
initSomeString
static initialiser
initSomeOtherString
whoopsy daisy
```

This is the behaviour that you're running into and is causing your problem. You're initialising `sessionFactory` by calling `buildSessionFactory()`, which relies upon `sProps` being initialised:

```
config.setProperty("hibernate.connection.url", sProps.getProperty("dburl")
                                               ^ This hasn't been initialised yet
```

The solution? **Move the declaration of `sessionFactory` to *below* your static initialiser block.**

Comment: +1 for the great detailed explanation. I should have accepted your answer but @blalasaadri gave me that tip first. SO should let accept more than one answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

The static block will be executed when the class is referenced the first time. (Instantiation or a reference to a static member)

Comment: Instantiation or a reference to a static **member** (method or field).

Answer (score 1):

The question you link to is just talking about compile-time constants; referencing them does not load the class. But anything you do to load the class -- for example, `Class.forName("HibernateUtil")` -- will necessarily run the static initializer.

Also, since the `static` variable you are dealing with is not a primitive type or a `String`, it can't be a compile-time constant anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The ClassLoader needs to load the class before it the static block executes. This happens when the class is referenced for the first time.

You could force this by using `Class.forName("");`. With this, you can use `final` variables

Comment: It's clear to me that I am missing something very fundamental. See my update above. Additional insights? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the class, e.g. calling it's static method, creating an instance of it, the static block will be executed.

Another way is to load the class explicitely by calling `Class.forName`. This is useful when you only know the name (as a string). Sometimes you have to scan the jar file to get the name and use `Class.forname` to load it.