# Java: static final String population in static block results in NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, string, static, final, static-block

I have this class:

```
public final class Validator {

    private static final String TEST_VALUE = "test";
    private static final String TEST;

    static {
        TEST = TEST_VALUE + "_test";
    }

    private Validator() {}

    public static void validate() {
        //Do something with TEST
    }
}
```

When I call `Validator.validate()` from somewhere else, I get an `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize ....Validator`

As I understand from [Static block in Java not executed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853747/static-block-in-java-not-executed), final static Strings are prepopulated at compile-time.

Is this the case if the variable is only defined in the static block? I would expect that the compiler would not try to pre-populate that final variable.

If it's not the case... What could be the error?

With a debugger I noticed that the static block is never executed, but I don't get why...

This is Java 8 btw.

**UPDATE:**

The problem was a java error in the static block. 
The strange thing is that there were no errors in the logs pointing to anything of the static block and the debugger did not halt at the static constructor, so I thought that the problem lied somewhere else.

Comment: Can you Provide a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Cannot reproduce your Problem and calling Validator.validate() from other classes works just fine for me.

Comment: You are right, when I make an isolated example with the above code, the problem does not occur, I'll do some research and update the question in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
static {
    TEST = TEST_VALUE + "_test";
}
```

is probably not your real code since it should not cause any runtime exception.
You rise a`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` because probably you encounter an exception in the static bloc :

```
static {
        TEST = TEST_VALUE + "_test";
      }
```

which prevents the class to be loaded.

You should check that you log suitably any exception which could occur at least in the standard output of the program.

Comment: You are right. The strange thing is that there is nothing in the logs (this could be due to the spring-framework). And with a debugger, it never gets in the static block... But I'm narrowing the the code in the static constructor to find the error

Comment: Indeed, by isolating step by step, you should find. If you don't manage to find the cause, don't hesitate to edit your question with more details.

Comment: The problem was a .split function with a dot that was incorrectly quoted in the static constructor...

Comment: Great. Static block or Class initializer. Static constructor doesn't exist in Java :)